Issues with ARM Translation Tools libhoudini
Can anyone help me?
I am trying to enable arm translation on an i686 device which is running Android 11 inside waydroid(kindof container like docker).
But either libhoudini and libndk doesn't work.
I even download libhoudini x version but still it doesn't work.
OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Gnome Version : 42.9
Display Server/ Windowing System: Wayland
Processor: Intel SSE 4.2 NOT SUPPORTED, SSE 4.1 Supported
Image : Lineage OS 18.2 Android 11 32 Bit GAPPS
I am trying from weeks to enable libHoudini translation on waydroid. But it doesn't work. There are a lot of errors in there. First I downloaded libhoudini7_x.sfs and then used the waydroid extras script to install libhoudini(y version) in waydroid. It extracts the zip files into the directory /var/lib/waydroid/overlay/system/ and there are four folders:
bin lib etc lib64
I deleted the lib64 folder. Then I extracted the houdini7_x.sfs(I just mounted it using nautilus file manager and then copied all items). Then I went to these folders and replaced the files of y version with x version.
Then I used gedit to open /var/lib/waydroid/waydroid_base.prop and then modified modified these lines:
ro.product.cpu.abilist=x86_64,x86,arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=x86_64,arm64-v8a
ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge=libhoudini.so
ro.enable.native.bridge.exec=1
ro.dalvik.vm.isa.arm=x86
ro.dalvik.vm.isa.arm64=x86_64

Into these lines:
ro.product.cpu.abilist=x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=x86_64,arm64-v8a(i just removed that)
ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge=libhoudini.so
ro.enable.native.bridge.exec=1
ro.dalvik.vm.isa.arm=x86
ro.dalvik.vm.isa.arm64=x86_64(i just removed that)

And then when I use sudo waydroid logcat and then open up my game it says:
08-19 15:00:57.621   224   251 I ActivityManager: Start proc 6048:com.dts.freefireth/u0a156 for pre-top-activity {com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity}
08-19 15:00:57.663  6048  6048 E libprocessgroup: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10156: Read-only file system
08-19 15:00:57.663  6048  6048 W Zygote  : createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
08-19 15:00:57.682   224  3497 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-19 15:00:57.683   224  3497 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) Binder:224_12 identical 1 line
08-19 15:00:57.684   224  3497 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-19 15:00:57.700  6048  6048 W .dts.freefiret: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-19 15:00:57.712   224  5742 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-19 15:00:57.814  6048  6048 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-19 15:00:57.814  6048  6048 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 15:00:57.814  6048  6048 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.dts.freefireth, PID: 6048
08-19 15:00:57.814  6048  6048 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~2gkwN1z6YYk9-UwCm47wJw==/com.dts.freefireth-4IfBONsA93AXGyuZvtVZhQ==/lib/arm/libanort.so" is for EM_ARM (40) instead of EM_386 (3)

And when I use y version, it says
Expected Feature SSE4_2 Not found
and some other features like this.
Now what should I do now?
When I tried to use libndk, first waydroid doesn't start saying:
/dev/anbox-binder has died
So I edited the abi list and removed x86_64 and armabiv8
After that, waydroid launchs but still black screen error with free fire.
Log:
9-03 11:04:11.006   226   253 I ActivityManager: Start proc 9960:com.dts.freefireth/u0a165 for pre-top-activity {com.dts.freefireth/com.dts.freefireth.FFMainActivity}
09-03 11:04:11.012  9960  9960 E libprocessgroup: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10165: Read-only file system
09-03 11:04:11.012  9960  9960 W Zygote  : createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
09-03 11:04:11.014  9960  9960 W .dts.freefiret: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-03 11:04:11.015  9960  9960 I ndk_translation: Initialized NDK translation (armv7l), version 0.2.3
09-03 11:04:11.016    43    43 I tombstoned: received crash request for pid 9960
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : LineageOS Version: '18.1-20240720-GAPPS-waydroid_x86'
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'waydroid/lineage_waydroid_x86/waydroid_x86:11/RQ3A.211001.001/97:userdebug/test-keys'
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2024-09-03 11:04:11+0500
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : pid: 9960, tid: 9960, name: .dts.freefiret  >>> zygote <<<
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : uid: 10165
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xe85800c5 (*pc=0xd0b80ff3)
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :     eax 00000001  ebx ddfc0000  ecx ddfc245c  edx 00000000
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :     edi 0000000c  esi ffc754d0
09-03 11:04:11.023  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :     ebp ffc75478  esp ffc753c0  eip e85800c5
09-03 11:04:11.074   226  3579 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
09-03 11:04:11.075   226  3579 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) Binder:226_17 identical 1 line
09-03 11:04:11.077   226  3579 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
09-03 11:04:11.117   226   282 I InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window or gesture monitor at (1045, 258) in display 0.
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : 
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 002670c5  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so ((anonymous namespace)::TinyElfLoader::Parse(void*, unsigned int, LoadedElfFile*)+757) (BuildId: ff7ce86ac9b06e63021a897977663898)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00266b0f  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (TinyLoader::LoadFromFile(char const*, unsigned int, void* (*)(void*, unsigned int, int, int, int, long long), int (*)(void*, unsigned int), LoadedElfFile*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+2063) (BuildId: ff7ce86ac9b06e63021a897977663898)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000cd3a1  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::GuestLoader::CreateInstance(char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+369) (BuildId: ff7ce86ac9b06e63021a897977663898)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 000cdb10  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::GuestLoader::StartAppProcessInNewThread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+48) (BuildId: ff7ce86ac9b06e63021a897977663898)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000e41ab  /system/lib/libndk_translation.so ((anonymous namespace)::native_bridge_initialize(android::NativeBridgeRuntimeCallbacks const*, char const*, char const*)+491) (BuildId: ff7ce86ac9b06e63021a897977663898)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00002df3  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libnativebridge.so (InitializeNativeBridge+371) (BuildId: c78ddc48f2edca8129db3aaacf963954)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00542fec  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::InitializeNativeBridge(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+60) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0064a105  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::InitNonZygoteOrPostFork(_JNIEnv*, bool, bool, art::Runtime::NativeBridgeAction, char const*, bool)+245) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00563aec  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ZygoteHooks_nativePostForkChild(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long long, int, unsigned char, unsigned char, _jstring*)+7180) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 00012b2a  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+218) (BuildId: c971e025c360eeee6c6f91e6fdefb8b9ab8aa9e0)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 00022741  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.ZygoteHooks.postForkChild+97) (BuildId: c971e025c360eeee6c6f91e6fdefb8b9ab8aa9e0)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 008b4e25  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.Zygote.callPostForkChildHooks+53) (BuildId: c977164e98c24a39cd2571070209c629374fcf56)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0013bd72  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 001d0612  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+258) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 00630623  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, char*)+579) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 00630af5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+85) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.139  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 004cf73f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+735) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 0008f87e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+62) (BuildId: 0fd81b1f779241269c69bfa7edfa3d63)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 0016bbc2  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so ((anonymous namespace)::SpecializeCommon(_JNIEnv*, unsigned int, unsigned int, _jintArray*, int, _jobjectArray*, long long, long long, int, _jstring*, _jstring*, bool, bool, _jstring*, _jstring*, bool, _jobjectArray*, _jobjectArray*, bool, bool)+10466) (BuildId: 0fd81b1f779241269c69bfa7edfa3d63)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 001669ef  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::com_android_internal_os_Zygote_nativeForkAndSpecialize(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, int, int, _jintArray*, int, _jobjectArray*, int, _jstring*, _jstring*, _jintArray*, _jintArray*, unsigned char, _jstring*, _jstring*, unsigned char, _jobjectArray*, _jobjectArray*, unsigned char, unsigned char)+1039) (BuildId: 0fd81b1f779241269c69bfa7edfa3d63)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 0023a4ea  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+554) (BuildId: c977164e98c24a39cd2571070209c629374fcf56)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 008b51b3  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.Zygote.forkAndSpecialize+227) (BuildId: c977164e98c24a39cd2571070209c629374fcf56)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 008ba07b  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.processOneCommand+2091) (BuildId: c977164e98c24a39cd2571070209c629374fcf56)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 008bf46e  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteServer.runSelectLoop+2078) (BuildId: c977164e98c24a39cd2571070209c629374fcf56)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 008bbf31  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1889) (BuildId: c977164e98c24a39cd2571070209c629374fcf56)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 0013bd72  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 001d0612  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+258) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 00630623  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, char*)+579) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 00630af5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+85) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 004cf73f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+735) (BuildId: 3217e29976a90e8b2cac233622413c0a)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 0008f87e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+62) (BuildId: 0fd81b1f779241269c69bfa7edfa3d63)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 00098bfe  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+910) (BuildId: 0fd81b1f779241269c69bfa7edfa3d63)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 000037e4  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1588) (BuildId: 9c71d85cc4699b295ed827e5039a1c19)
09-03 11:04:11.140  9960  9960 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 000937f3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+115) (BuildId: 126193a17beb286080682934e05a7bff)
09-03 11:04:11.156   226   282 I InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window or gesture monitor at (1045, 260) in display 0.
09-03 11:04:11.165   226   282 I InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window or gesture monitor at (1045, 264) in display 0.
09-03 11:04:11.172   226   282 I InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window or gesture monitor at (1042, 268) in display 0.
09-03 11:04:11.182   226   282 I InputDispatcher: Dropping event because there is no touchable window or gesture monitor at (1039, 272) in display 0.


Can anyone help me?
Do I spoof the processor? (Using the processor info file found in /var/lib/waydroid directory.
Or just switch back to Windows to use Bluestacks
gunwar waydroid log.md
waydroid free fire log.md
Waydroid version
1.4.2
Device
Linux Desktop
Operating System
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Kernel version
6.5.0-44-generic
Desktop Environment
Gnome 42.9
GPU
AMD ATI Radeon HD 5000/6000/735
